# Can you cast a pointer to a pointer to the first member?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Given:

```
struct Foo { int a; int b; };
struct Bar { Foo foo; int c; };
```

Is this well-defined?

```
void f(Bar *bar) {
    auto foo = (Foo*)bar;
    cout << foo->a << ',' << foo->b;
}
```

Clang translates code using inheritance, to the equivalent of the above, but I want to make sure it's defined by the standard.

Comment: Why do You need to do this?

Comment: You might want to add `language-lawyer` tag, especially if you want chapter and verse from the standard.

Comment: @Eljay Good idea, thanks!

Comment: I was going to point to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/, but then the question was closed, and at least one answer in the link provided does the same thing.

Comment: But as @RobertAndrzejuk asks, "why do you want this?" when you could just use &bar->foo ?

Comment: As per the other Q&A, it seems that "standard layout" requirement is rather easily/inadvertently violated.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Because there might be several Bar's each with a Foo as the first member.